# For Each Loop Ranges VBA Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

```
If Range("D32").Value = 2 Then
   If Range("D15").Value = 0 Then
      Range("D15").Value = 1
      Range("D32").Value = 1
   End If
End If
```

I've been trying to figure out how to put these values within a for each loop.

Basically if D15->AE15 = 2 and D32->AE32 = 0 change both of the values to 1.

I thought about repeating the above nested IF statement for every cell.. but that would take a bit of time.

```
For Each c In Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D32:AE32").Value

If Range("D32") = 2 Then


Range("D15").Value = 1
Range("D32").Value = 1

End If
Next c
```

That works for one cell. However i'm stumped on how to get it to check the whole row and then change the corresponding column values for 15 and 32 when one is 2.

Comment: Sorry I should've elaborated more i've edited my original question.

Comment: In your for each line you need to give it a collection. `For Each cell In Range("D32:AE32").Cells` will give you all the cells in that range. I'll elaborate in an answer.

Comment: Awesome, but how would I get the values to update throughout the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you're on the right track:

```
Sub ChgValues()
    Dim c As Range, d As Range

    For Each c In Range("D15:AE15")
        Set d = c.Offset(17, 0)
        If c.Value = 0 And d.Value = 2 Then
            c.Value = 1
            d.Value = 1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

**edit:**
The above code will check for a 0 in row 15 and a 2 in row 32, for all columns from D to AE. If the values could also be the other way around (2 in row 15, 0 in row 32) then an additional comparison is needed:

change

```
If c.Value = 0 And d.Value = 2 Then
```

to

```
If (c.Value = 0 And d.Value = 2) or (c.Value = 2 And d.Value = 0) Then
```

Comment: This seems to only change column D. Not s(when s32 is 0 and s15 is 2) I'll work with it though thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the for each loop a collection and then check values.

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("D15:AE15").Cells
    If cell.Value = 0 And cell.Offset(17).Value = 2 Then
        cell.Value = 1
        cell.Offset(17).Value = 1
    End If
Next cell
```